# Adding entities at runtime with EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Is it posible to add model types at runtime with entity framework 4.0?

The reason is that the application I am working on will be installed on different database servers and certain tables will have different names.

Thanks

Comment: Must it be runtime? Would changing it at deployment time be sufficient?

Comment: @Steven, The app will be installed on almost over 30 database servers each having only certain tables with different names, so I guess it must be at runtime.

Comment: But once an application is running, the database schema does not change all of a sudden, or does it?

Comment: My point is, you can configure EF to load the EDMX from disk, so you can generate or transform the EDMX file once for each application. You don't have to do this runtime. You can do this as part of the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to modify EDM model at runtime.